# How many electrons are in each shell?

Tags: code-golf

Given a atomic number, print how many electrons are in each shell of the element that the atomic number corresponds to.

### Expected input/output:

```
Input -> Output
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 2, 1
4 -> 2, 2
5 -> 2, 3
6 -> 2, 4
7 -> 2, 5
8 -> 2, 6
9 -> 2, 7
10 -> 2, 8
11 -> 2, 8, 1
12 -> 2, 8, 2
13 -> 2, 8, 3
14 -> 2, 8, 4
15 -> 2, 8, 5
16 -> 2, 8, 6
17 -> 2, 8, 7
18 -> 2, 8, 8
19 -> 2, 8, 8, 1
20 -> 2, 8, 8, 2
21 -> 2, 8, 9, 2
22 -> 2, 8, 10, 2
23 -> 2, 8, 11, 2
24 -> 2, 8, 13, 1
25 -> 2, 8, 13, 2
26 -> 2, 8, 14, 2
27 -> 2, 8, 15, 2
28 -> 2, 8, 16, 2
29 -> 2, 8, 18, 1
30 -> 2, 8, 18, 2
31 -> 2, 8, 18, 3
32 -> 2, 8, 18, 4
33 -> 2, 8, 18, 5
34 -> 2, 8, 18, 6
35 -> 2, 8, 18, 7
36 -> 2, 8, 18, 8
37 -> 2, 8, 18, 8, 1
38 -> 2, 8, 18, 8, 2
39 -> 2, 8, 18, 9, 2
40 -> 2, 8, 18, 10, 2
41 -> 2, 8, 18, 12, 1
42 -> 2, 8, 18, 13, 1
43 -> 2, 8, 18, 13, 2
44 -> 2, 8, 18, 15, 1
45 -> 2, 8, 18, 16, 1
46 -> 2, 8, 18, 18
47 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 1
48 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 2
49 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 3
50 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 4
51 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 5
52 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 6
53 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 7
54 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 8
55 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 8, 1
56 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 8, 2
57 -> 2, 8, 18, 18, 9, 2
58 -> 2, 8, 18, 19, 9, 2
59 -> 2, 8, 18, 21, 8, 2
60 -> 2, 8, 18, 22, 8, 2
61 -> 2, 8, 18, 23, 8, 2
62 -> 2, 8, 18, 24, 8, 2
63 -> 2, 8, 18, 25, 8, 2
64 -> 2, 8, 18, 25, 9, 2
65 -> 2, 8, 18, 27, 8, 2
66 -> 2, 8, 18, 28, 8, 2
67 -> 2, 8, 18, 29, 8, 2
68 -> 2, 8, 18, 30, 8, 2
69 -> 2, 8, 18, 31, 8, 2
70 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 8, 2
71 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 9, 2
72 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 10, 2
73 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 11, 2
74 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 12, 2
75 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 13, 2
76 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 14, 2
77 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 15, 2
78 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 17, 1
79 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 1
80 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 2
81 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 3
82 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 4
83 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 5
84 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 6
85 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 7
86 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 8
87 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 8, 1
88 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 8, 2
89 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 9, 2
90 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 10, 2
91 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 20, 9, 2
92 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 21, 9, 2
93 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 22, 9, 2
94 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 24, 8, 2
95 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 25, 8, 2
96 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 25, 9, 2
97 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 27, 8, 2
98 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 28, 8, 2
99 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 29, 8, 2
100 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 30, 8, 2
101 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 31, 8, 2
102 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 8, 2
103 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 8, 3
104 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 10, 2
105 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 11, 2
106 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 12, 2
107 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 13, 2
108 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 14, 2
109 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 15, 2
110 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 16, 3
111 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 17, 2
112 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 2
113 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 3
114 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 4
115 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 5
116 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 6
117 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 7
118 -> 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 8
```

<sub>Psst... take a closer look at the output, it's not always the last shell incrementing.</sub>

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=94753,OVERRIDE_USER=12537;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: It's been a while since I took chemistry. Could you please remind us what decides where electrons go?

Comment: Waiting for the inevitable Mathematica built-in

Comment: Actually, this looks to be the exact same as [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37657/20260). You should search for dupes before writing, or at least before posting.

Comment: @Suever 42 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
Tr/@#~ElementData~"ElectronConfiguration"&
```